# C++ application runned as a service, can't shutdown the PC

Tags: c++, bash, unix, service, shutdown

I have a simple application written in C++ under Linux. The main.cpp file is like the following:

```
int main()
{
   system("sudo shutdown +1")
   return 0;
}
```

Compiling this file will produce an application called **myShutdown**.

I created a bash script (named **myBash**) with just two lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
./myShutdown
```

The script works perfectly and, if I run it, my PC shutdown in a minute.

Now, I created a service called **myService.service** that just run my script.
Running the service (the service has been put in the right folder and so on)  does not produce anything. The PC do not shutdown. Why do I have this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: the script run with your privileges. while the service run as an unprivileged user. You will need to give some permissions to the service

Comment: Hi @litelite. The problem is that if the script is something like:

#!/bin/sh
sudo shutdown +1

It works both ways. The problem shows when it's not the script who call shutdown, but the application runned by the script